# I don't know how to install wireshark on my mininet

Tags: wireshark, mininet

I have followed the mininet walkthrough and am unable to install Wireshark: http://mininet.org/walkthrough/

I tried `git clone https://github.com/mininet/mininet`

I am trying to run Wireshark on mininet using an ssh session, but it does not work, I get this error:

> fatal: destination path 'mininet' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Thank you very much.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm0w1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The error message you got means the directory is already there, you do not need to clone it using `git`. So go ahead and continue following the Mininet walkthrough (by running `mininet/util/install.sh -w`).

By the way, Wireshark would usually be installed by default if you are using the Mininet VM or if you chose to install Mininet from source with the `-a` flag.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm trying it. :D